# Repetitve seach and replace on constantly changing file. Python

Tags: python, windows

So I'm trying to have a script that will run every 3 seconds to read a text file, clean it up and write is as another text file. The original text file is always changing. It's from a music playout program, current song title. I went collecting bits of python code around the internet and personalizing them to my needs. Right now I have a script that will work perfectly,each command and the scheduling. But when the original file changes again, then the script gives an error. Any idea how this could be fixed?

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "radio_script.py", line 29, in <module>
   executeSomthing<>
File "radio_script.py", line 10, in executeSomething
  for line in intext:
IoError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I'm running the python script on Windows. 
So when the script is run, if a line contains any of the "delete_lin" words the whole line is deleted. While each of the "line replace" entries replace those words with nothing, just as they are supposed to. 
Here is my script.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
delete_lin = ['VP', 'VH', 'VT', 'VB', 'VS', 'BG']
import time
import os
def executeSomething():
    with open('current.txt', 'r') as intext, open('currentedit.txt', 'w') as outfile:
       for line in intext:
         if not any(delete_lin in line for delete_lin in delete_lin):
           line = line.replace('(email)', "")                           
           line = line.replace('_AO VIVO', "")
           line = line.replace('Ao Vivo', "")
           line = line.replace('AO VIVO', "")
           line = line.replace('(04)', "")
           line = line.replace('2016', "")
           line = line.replace('2015', "")
           line = line.replace('2014', "")
           line = line.replace('2013', "")
           outfile.write(line)
           outfile.flush()
           intext.flush()
           print 'Pause'
           time.sleep(3)

while True:
    executeSomething()
```

Comment: Does the program ever get out of the `for` loop? You're sleeping for 3 seconds for each line in the original file.

Comment: I believe it does get out because, if I add a print command before "with open" it will print ever 3 seconds. And sleeping for each line is not a problem for me because the original file only has one line. Although could that be what's giving me problems?

Comment: You should definitely move the `sleep` statement outside the loop for clarity, but if printing before the with shows, it's not the problem.  It might be because you aren't closing the file in between, and so it's trying to read a no longer valid file? try adding `intext.close()` after the loop..?

Comment: Well actually, I tried running the scheduler in one script and the parsing in another and found that when the original file changes it wouldn't 'print' before the 'with open'. I don't know if this is the best place but I moved the sleep to before the with open. And I deleted outfile.flush and intext.flush and added outfile.close. Now it seem to be working perfectly. The intext.close would always give me "i/o operation on closed file." Thank you Will.

Comment: Glad that worked, I'll add an official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the original file is modified, the file reference `intext` is no longer a valid file.  While the path is the same, the actual file has been modified.  Thus, you should call `intext.close()` at the end of the `for` loop.  To make sure it is actually recreating the file reference make sure to only `sleep` outside the loop.